# how to exit a function when an event is set?

Tags: python, events

I have an infinite loop thread that sets an event when a sensor is high/true

```
event  = threading.Event()

def eventSetter():
    while True:
        if sensor:
            event.set()
        else:
            event.clear()

th1 = threading.thread(target=eventSetter)
th1.start
```

and I have a function capture that takes 5 sec to execute

```
def capture():
    time.sleep(2) #sleep represents a task that takes 2 sec to finish
    time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(2)
    return
```

now I want to exit the function capture in the middle of its task whenever the event is set

for example if task 1 takes 5sec to finish and the event occurs at time 2sec, the task should not continue at time 2sec and the function should exit

---

I tried checking for the event every line but i don't know how to exit in the middle of its task thus it waits for the task to finish before return applies also I didn't like the look of multiple if/return

```
def capture():
    time.sleep(2) #sleep represents a task that takes sec to finish
    if event.is_set():
        return
    time.sleep(1)
    if event.is_set():
        return
    time.sleep(2)
    if event.is_set():
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to check the event state every chance you get in order to break out of `capture` as soon as possible. The variation you provided is fine, but here are a couple other ways to do the same thing:

```py
def capture():
    # nested checks are fine with only a few tasks but can get awkward
    # when the indentation gets too deep to be easily readable
    time.sleep(2) # task 1
    if not event.is_set()
        time.sleep(1) # task 2
        if not event.is_set():
            time.sleep(2) # task 3
```

```py
def capture():
    # defining a list of functions to be executed is great when there
    # are many subtasks but can be overkill if there are just a few
    from functools import partial
    subtasks = [
        partial(time.sleep, 2), # first task
        partial(time.sleep, 1), # second task
        partial(time.sleep, 2)  # third task
    ]

    for subtask in subtasks:
        if event.is_set():
            return
        subtask()
```

Comment: if task 1 takes 5sec to finish for example, and the event occurs at time 2sec, would this wait for the whole 5sec to finish before exiting the function?

Comment: Yes. There's nothing you can do about that unless you can break up task 1 into parts and check the event state between those parts.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the task, you may be able to move it into a separate process using the `multiprocessing` library and run it in the background with the ability to kill it from the parent process. (Note you can't do this with threads, only processes.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want breaking loop ?

if you want break any time or condition you need to `break` `key.

for example

```
event  = threading.Event()
def eventSetter():
    while True:
        if sensor:
            event.set()
            break
            #loop stoped.
        else:
            event.clear()

     return True #or none.
```

Comment: I was referring to the def capture():

i want to cancel the operation of the function capture when the event is set.

the eventSetter just constantly checking for value of sensor and sets an event